# Installing R development version in Conda environment

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I would like to install R development version (i.e. latest daily snapshot) inside a `conda` environment. I haven't found any `conda` package that would allow me to install such a version from `conda` directly. I can install it from source, but I'm not sure how well that would work. Any suggestion on whether this is possible or do you know of any other preferable way to perform the installation? I'm aware I could use a container, but I'd rather avoid that option for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Anaconda Cloud channels build the R development version.

Answer (score 0):

Conda is a package manager that works with non-Python packages as well. Before installing any packages, you should set up a new conda environment with `conda create -n env-name` (replace `env-name` with your desired name). Then you need to activate it with `conda activate r-env`. Then you can install the essential R packages with `conda install r-essentials -c conda-forge`.

In case you are unfamiliar with the `-c` flag, it tells conda to look at a specific channel when looking for your packages. `-c conda-forge` thus searches on the `conda-forge`-channel.

Comment: The `r` channel has not been update in years. Conda R users should use `conda-forge` instead.